# display view as popup in codeigniter when tank authentication library is used

Tags: codeigniter, view, popup, blogs, tankauth

I am developing blog in codeigniter using tank authentication library(downloaded from net)

As you know blog contain like/dislike button .When click on like button(a view page) ,first control is transfer to controller  where it is checked whether user is logged in or not,if user is logged in then control is transferred back to main blog page and blog is liked(ie like counter is incremented)
but, if user is not logged in or is not the member of community then login/register form is displayed.

These all functionality is in-build in tank authentication library is it is working fine.

Problem:
I want that if user is not logged in or is not a member ,then whichever page is displayed(login/register/forgot password/send email again),they should be opened in pop up on click of like/dislike button.

Work done:
Used anchor popup function but no use.
Result:It display view in new window

Placed the view of login/register form on same blog page,used jquery (fade in,fade out)etc function to display pop up.
Result:pop up is displayed, but as that pop up is not coming from controller so is of no use.(as tank authentication library function are not getting envolved.)

So if possible then please help me to display view(called from controller as pop up).
If possible then do send some proper links or any demo project.
There is a function of jquery-fancy box,I guess that would work.
I know the problem will be solved by applying concept of jquery+ mvc flow, but as I am new to php as well as codeigniter so I am not able to integrate my thoughts properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: bootstraps modal should do the trick

Comment: how is bootstrap envolve in this?

Comment: bootstraps model is kind of "pop up markup" it is easy to use, you may check it out here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals I know it is far from your project if you are not using bootstrap at all but reconsider your options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Fancybox` your problem will be solved. [Download] the package first. Then include the `CSS` and `JS` in your template.[1](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/v2.1.5)

Usage:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>home/login/" class="fancybox">Login</a>
$(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type        : 'iframe',
        autoSize : false,
        width    : "60%",
        height   : "56%",
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade'
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
Changes :
added the `fancybox` class in the link.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/blog/ajax_dislike/?dislikeid=<?php echo $row ->id;?>" class="fancybox">Dislike</a>
```

Mandatory includes in the `<head>` section of the index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

Now in the page in the `<head>` section include this after the above includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type        : 'iframe',
        autoSize : false,
        width    : "60%",
        height   : "56%",
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where should I write fancybox() function,on the view page from where I am calling controller (by giving link in href,as told above),or on the view page of login form.

Comment: In your view file. Include `Jquery.js`, `fancybox.js` and `fancybox.css` in your view too.

Comment: this  is not my question,I am asking in which view file should I include it..I have got many view files..the one view file from where I am calling my controller or login page view file. Is there any issue that fancy box is supported only by some versions of jquery.

Comment: Include in the view where you will be placing the `<a>` tag clicking on which you want to open the popup. See the documentation of fancybox  for more info about it. In my opinion include the latest version of `Jquery`

Comment: this is again back to original story,this is mvc structure u know.<a> tag will be placed in one view file(index.php which will call controller),the other view page is login.php....which has to be displayed in popup.Now where should I place jquery code in index.php (which will call controller) or login.php(which has to be displayed as popup).Please do reply (if possible then with proper example) this is urgent project...thanks

Comment: I am trying your fancybox code from morning but still problem not solved yet

Comment: Please post your view in your question again.

Comment: which one? index page view or login page view?

Comment: Please post both that will be better

Comment: in my index page  :   <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/blog/ajax_dislike/?dislikeid=<?php echo $row ->id;?>">Dislike</a>  on click of this,function named ajax_dislike of blog controller is call,if the user is not logged in the control is transfered to login function of auth controller.All authentication is taking place via tank auth library.This login function of auth controller loads a view page that contain a login form.(another view page).All this is working fine,now I want that this login page should be showed as a popup.Now where should I place your jquery function n how  it wrk